# String flashvar coming out as [Object object] rather than string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm sending

```
flashvars.location = "xml/";
```

But it's ending up as:

```
  [object Object]
```

when I try to use it.

Here's how I assign it and use it.

```
xmlLocation =  (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.location) ? FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters : "";

myLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlLocation.toString() + "service.xml"));
```

How can I make this a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are making an incorrect assignment.

When your ternary expression is `true`, you set the variable `xmlLocation` equal to `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters`.  So now `xmlLocation` is the parameters object, not the `String` you are expecting.  Instead do this:

```
xmlLocation =  (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.location) ?
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.location : "";
```